# How to clear field using nightwatch framework?

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch

I'm trying to clear input field using different ways:

1. clearValue() - doesn't work
2. send some combination ok keys - doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing the Input with the Webriver-Key commands?

In my Project i do it like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < amountChars; i++) {
            browser.keys(WEBDRIVER_KEYS['Backspace']);
        }
```

WEBDRIVER_KEYS is part of the spectron-keys npm package.

Comment: .getValue('input[name="name"]', function(result) {
            console.log(result.value);
            (new Array(result.value.length)).fill().forEach(() => {
              browser.keys(browser.Keys.BACK_SPACE)
            });

it's working for me

Answer (score 3):

I have the following code which worked for me

```
.setValue('field, [
    browser.Keys.CONTROL,
    "a",
    browser.Keys.DELETE,
  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear value, setting empty value ?
Like this

```
.setValue('field', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I´ve made a custom command like this:

```
 this.waitForElementVisible(fieldSelector)
        .execute(
            function (fieldSelector) {
                const field = document.querySelector(fieldSelector);
                field.value = null;
            },
            [fieldSelector]
        );
```

And then in the test file i just call it like this:

```
browser.clearField(fieldSelector)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works like a charm:

```
browser.getValue('css selector', '#id', (textValue) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < textValue.value.length; i ++) {
            this.setValue('#id', '\u0008'); 
        }
});
```

Had to come up with this kind of a solution, since any of the provided ones didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.clearValue('yourTargetFieldSelector')
```

So in case of using Page object:

```
yourPageObjectInstance.clearValue('@yourTargetFieldSelector')
```

Answer (score 0):

I really suffered with this one today, so I share my solution  since none of the other solutions worked for me for chrome & firefox:

```
exports.command = function (fieldSelector) {
  const browserName = this.options.desiredCapabilities.browserName;

  if (browserName === 'chrome') {
    this.getValue(fieldSelector, function (result) {
      this.setValue(fieldSelector, [...(result.value || '')].map(char => '\u0008'));
    });
  } else {
    this.clearValue(fieldSelector);
  }

  return this;
};
```

This is a command to do  one thing for chrome and other one for firefox